# How to control visibility of view inside Master items in MasterDetailsView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I'm looking for a way to handle the visibility of nested items in a list for MasterDetailsView. Is there a way I can use the `ShowButton` boolean I created to control the visibility of an item (more button - with an ellipsis) within the list items used in my MasterDetailsView? Would I need to use dependency properties in this case or should something else be used?

**Expected result**

[image]

**Current result**

[image]

**XAML**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MD.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MD"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView x:Name="MyMasterDetailsView"
                                    BackButtonBehavior="Automatic" 
                                    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Emails}"
                                    NoSelectionContent="Select an item to view"
                                    CompactModeThresholdWidth="720">
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,8">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding From}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   Opacity=".6"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                                x:Name="MoreBtn" 
                                Background="Transparent" 
                                Content="&#xE712;" 
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Margin="10" 
                                Padding="10" 
                                Click="MoreBtn_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RelativePanel Margin="24">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding From}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   Margin="12,-6,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Body" 
                                   Text="{Binding Body}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
                    </RelativePanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Mail" 
                                    RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform 
                                  ScaleX="2" 
                                  ScaleY="2"/>
                            </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                        </SymbolIcon>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                                   FontSize="24" 
                                   Margin="0,12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
                <CommandBar>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back"/>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward"/>

                    <CommandBar.Content>
                        <TextBlock Margin="12,14">
              <Run Text="{Binding Emails.Count}" />
              <Run Text="Items" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </CommandBar.Content>
                </CommandBar>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
            <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
                <CommandBar>
                    <AppBarButton Icon="MailReply" Label="Reply" />
                    <AppBarButton Icon="MailReplyAll" Label="Reply All" />
                    <AppBarButton Icon="MailForward" Label="Forward" />
                </CommandBar>
            </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Item class (Email)**

```
public class Email
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool ShowButton { get; set; }
}

public class MyEmailManager
{
    public static List<Email> GetEmails()
    {
        var MyEmails = new List<Email>
        {
            new Email
            {
                From = "Steve Johnson",
                Body = "Are you available for lunch tomorrow? A client would like to discuss a project with you.",
                ShowButton = true
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "Pete Davidson",
                Body = "Don't forget the kids have their soccer game this Friday. We have to supply end of game snacks.",
                ShowButton = false
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "OneDrive",
                Body = "Your new album.\r\nYou uploaded some photos to your OneDrive and automatically created an album for you.",
                ShowButton = false
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "Twitter",
                Body = "Here are some people we think you might like to follow:\r\n.@randomPerson\r\nAPersonYouMightKnow",
                ShowButton = true
            }
        };

        return MyEmails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would I need to use dependency properties in this case or should something else be used?

You have no need use dependency properties in this case, you could bind MoreBtn's `Visibility` to `ShowButton` property directly.

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" 
        x:Name="MoreBtn" 
        Background="Transparent" 
        Content="&#xE712;" 
        Visibility="{Binding ShowButton}"
        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="10" 
        Padding="10" 
        Click="MoreBtn_Click"/>
```

> Starting in Windows 10, [**version 1607**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension#properties-of-the-binding-class-that-can-be-set-with-binding), the XAML framework provides a built in boolean to Visibility converter. The converter maps true to the Visible enumeration value and false to Collapsed so you can bind a Visibility property to a boolean without creating a converter. To use the built in converter, your app's minimum target SDK version must be 14393 or later. You can't use it when your app targets earlier versions of Windows 10. For more info about target versions, see Version adaptive code.

For previous version we could use [`BoolToVisibilityConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.converters.booltovisibilityconverter?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) to convert bool to visibility (install [**Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/) nuget package).

**Usage**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MasterDetailViewTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:converters="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Converters"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:MasterDetailViewTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >

<Page.Resources>
    <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="MyConveter" />
</Page.Resources>

......

<Button
    x:Name="MoreBtn"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="10"
    Padding="10"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Background="Transparent"
    Click="MoreBtn_Click"
    Content="&#xE712;"
    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
    Visibility="{Binding ShowButton, Converter={StaticResource MyConveter}}"
    />
```